# Chexbox ChekState functionality in Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, forms

I need a checkbox  which will ask the user:"Do you need to add an address?" and if user clicks on it then address label and textbox appears on the form ( I mean By default they were invisible and then I have changed this state), I have implemented this functionality by CheckboxSate event but what if the user doesn't click on the checkbox  at all, in this case after submission external details I am not able to move forward ( i mean after clicking on the next button my form don't call another subform, but when I check/uncheck checkbox it works correctly), is there any way to edit/update form validation or any default checkbox property in order to get rid of this bag?, here is my CheckState Event's code:

```
Private Sub AddAddress_CheckedStatrChange_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddAddress.CheckStateChanged
If AddAddress.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
                AddAddressLabel.Visible = True
                AddAddressTextBox.Visible = True
                AddAddressTextBox.Enabled = True



            ElseIf AddAddress.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked Then
                AddAddressLabel.Visible = False
                AddAddressTextBox.Visible = False
                AddAddressTextBox.Enabled = False

            End If
END Sub
```

Comment: I would extract this functionality into a separate method, and then use that method when loading your form.

Comment: Firstly, there's no such thing as `CheckboxState`. A `CheckBox` control has a `Checked` property and a `CheckState` property. You are using the wrong one. Only use `CheckState` if you care about all three states, which will only be the case if you have set the `ThreeState` property to `True`. If `ThreeState` is `False` then you only care about two states, so use the `Checked` property and `CheckedChanged` event only.

Comment: If you use the right event and property then there's no need for an `If` statement at all. `Checked` is `Boolean` and so is `Visible` so you just assign one to the other, e.g. `AddAddressLabel.Visible = AddAddress.Checked`.

Comment: That code doesn't make sense anyway. You're handling an event of `AddFTP` and then using a property of `AddAddress`. Not only are you handling the wrong event but you're also handling an event of the wrong object. The fact that your method has a "_1" on the end is the clue that you have created two handlers for the same event. You need to spend some time actually reading and debugging your code before posting here. A breakpoint or two would have told you a lot, if you'd bothered.

Answer (score 1):

That's how you would do:

```
Sub AddFTP_CheckedChanged() Handles AddFTP.CheckedChanged
     AddAddressLabel.Visible = Not AddAddressLabel.Visible
     AddAddressTextBox.Visible = Not AddAddressTextBox.Visible
     AddAddressTextBox.Enabled = Not AddAddressTextBox.Enabled 'It's useless since it's not visible
End Sub
```